# Is there an Open Source J2EE Server that works with IIS 7

Tags: iis, jakarta-ee

I have a (old) web app that is using Jrun and IIS. I would like to replace JRun with something free and OS. Can you recommend something that I can just install and copy the app jar files over and be up and running?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a full J2EE (damn, that must be old software), [Connecting IIS with Tomcat using isapi_redirect](http://blog.techstacks.com/2008/09/connecting-iis-with-tomcat-using.html) describes how to front [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) with IIS (covers version 7).

If you are running EJBs, I would consider using the (appropriate) version of [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) and follow the same procedure as above to front JBoss with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I use Jetty.  Very easy to use. Not sure if you have EJBs - the version of Jetty I use is just Servlets and JSP.

I've also used Tomcat and JBoss.  They work too.

Answer (score 0):

WebsphereCE from IBM is also open source. It is a scaled down version of the paid version. Some people reported success using it with IIS but you might want to use either Tomcat or Jetty if all you have are servlets and JSPs.